# WP Plugin: using add_filter inside of a class

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP v3.3.1, and I am trying to make a plugin. I have gotten it semi-working. It initiated, and add_action works, but for some reason my filters don't get triggered. When I googled around, I saw I was supposed to do it like this, but it is not working. I also tried including it outside of the class, which didn't work either. The error log is written to from the constructor, but not the `xmlAddMethod`. I tested the xmlrpc call in a single file, and it worked, but having problems making classes.

```
//DOESN'T WORK HERE
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', array( &$this, 'xmlAddMethod') );

class TargetDomain extends Domain 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {        
        error_log('TARGET: __construct');
        //DOESN'T WORK HERE EITHER
        add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', array( &$this, 'xmlAddMethod') );
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function xmlAddMethod( $methods ) 
    {
        error_log('TARGET: xml_add_method');
        $methods['myBlog.publishPost'] = 'publishMyPost';
        return $methods;
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change this:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', array( &$this, 'xmlAddMethod') );
```

To:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', array( 'TargetDomain', 'xmlAddMethod') );
```

Comment: @Revious It's not strange at all. Functions are different from Class Methods. The second arguments of [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) accept a variable of type [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). Callable types in PHP are either strings (functions), arrays (class methods), or anonymous functions (callbacks) that can be provided.

Comment: so the PHP interpreter looks for a function if he sees a string passed to a callable parameter, and a class method if he sees an array. Is it correct?

Comment: @Revious For the most part, correct. That is the general rule of thumb. There is the case in which strings that resemble a call to a static class method call can be passed (ie: `'SomeClass::staticMethod'`) which has been around since PHP 5.3, but that's the only exception to the rule that I can think of. In those cases, `'SomeClass::staticMethod'` would be identical to `['SomeClass', 'staticMethod']`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use php's magic **__CLASS__** constant.

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', array( __CLASS__, 'xmlAddMethod') );
```

Comment: Note that this is also true, but only when the call to `add_filter` is occurring within a class context. When used outside of a class like in OP's question, the `__CLASS__` magic constant will yield a blank / empty string.